# How is a username determined and can I hide the domain component in a winbind username?

Tags: users, samba, kerberos, nsswitch, winbind

Someone asked [a question](https://serverfault.com/q/563277/135566) on Server Fault about a problem which I'm also having but no one has answered it so I'm posing a slightly different question to try and figure it out myself.

I've configured PAM on my Arch Linux server to use [pam_krb5](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pam-krb5/) and it works.

```
login as: Username
Username@server.ad.example.com's password:
Warning: Your password will expire in 32 days on Tue Apr  1 22:24:58 2014
Last login: Fri Feb 28 09:46:58 2014 from pc.ad.example.com
Could not chdir to home directory /home/AD/Username: No such file or directory
[AD\Username@server /]$ echo $KRB5CCNAME
FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_3000019_DF0uwI
[AD\Username@server /]$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_3000019_DF0uwI
Default principal: Username@AD.EXAMPLE.COM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
28/02/14 10:03:43  28/02/14 20:03:43  krbtgt/AD.EXAMPLE.COM@AD.EXAMPLE.COM
        renew until 01/03/14 10:03:43
```

*I haven't created the home directory yet so I think that error can be ignored for the time being.*

And the logs show the following.

```
sshd[10567]: pam_krb5(sshd:auth): pam_sm_authenticate: entry (nonull)
sshd[10567]: pam_krb5(sshd:auth): (user Username) attempting authentication as Username@AD.EXAMPLE.COM
sshd[10567]: pam_krb5(sshd:auth): user Username authenticated as Username@AD.EXAMPLE.COM
sshd[10567]: pam_krb5(sshd:auth): (user Username) temporarily storing credentials in /tmp/krb5cc_pam_7mIl6Q
sshd[10567]: pam_krb5(sshd:auth): pam_sm_authenticate: exit (success)
sshd[10567]: pam_krb5(sshd:account): pam_sm_acct_mgmt: entry
sshd[10567]: pam_krb5(sshd:account): (user Username) retrieving principal from cache
sshd[10567]: pam_krb5(sshd:account): pam_sm_acct_mgmt: exit (success)
sshd[10567]: Accepted password for Username from 192.168.1.10 port 50653 ssh2
sshd[10567]: pam_krb5(sshd:setcred): pam_sm_setcred: entry (establish)
sshd[10567]: pam_krb5(sshd:setcred): (user Username) initializing ticket cache FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_3000019_CgGnZS
sshd[10567]: pam_krb5(sshd:setcred): pam_sm_setcred: exit (success)
kernel: type=1006 audit(1393584192.561:70): pid=10567 uid=0 old auid=4294967295 new auid=3000019 old ses=4294967295 new ses=69 res=1
sshd[10567]: pam_krb5(sshd:session): pam_sm_open_session: entry
sshd[10567]: pam_krb5(sshd:session): pam_sm_open_session: exit (success)
sshd[10569]: pam_krb5(sshd:setcred): pam_sm_setcred: entry (establish)
sshd[10569]: pam_krb5(sshd:setcred): pam_sm_setcred: exit (success)
```

Great.

When I try `kinit` it detects the principal correctly.

```
[AD\Username@server /]$ kinit
Password for Username@AD.EXAMPLE.COM:
Warning: Your password will expire in 32 days on Tue 01 Apr 2014 22:24:58 BST
```

However, when I try to use `sudo` it interprets the username as the principal.

```
[AD\Username@server /]$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for AD\Username:
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
```

And the log shows the following.

```
sudo[10564]: pam_krb5(sudo:auth): pam_sm_authenticate: entry (silent)
sudo[10564]: pam_krb5(sudo:auth): (user AD\Username) attempting authentication as ADUsername@AD.EXAMPLE.COM
sudo[10564]: pam_krb5(sudo:auth): (user AD\Username) krb5_get_init_creds_password: Client 'ADUsername@AD.EXAMPLE.COM' not found in Kerberos database
sudo[10564]: pam_krb5(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=AD\Username uid=3000019 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/0 ruser=AD\Username rhost=
sudo[10564]: pam_krb5(sudo:auth): pam_sm_authenticate: exit (failure)
sudo[10564]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=AD\Username uid=3000019 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/0 ruser=AD\Username rhost=  user=AD\Username
sudo[10564]: pam_krb5(sudo:auth): pam_sm_authenticate: entry (silent)
sudo[10564]: pam_krb5(sudo:auth): (user AD\Username) error getting password: Authentication failure
sudo[10564]: pam_krb5(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=AD\Username uid=3000019 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/0 ruser=AD\Username rhost=
sudo[10564]: pam_krb5(sudo:auth): pam_sm_authenticate: exit (failure)
```

I have winbind configured in nsswitch.conf and I presume it is this which decides the username should be "AD\Username" rather than just "Username". So firstly am I right in thinking it is up to the winbind library what the user's name appears to be?

And secondly, how can I configure winbind so that if the user is in the default Kerberos realm (as defined by `/etc/krb5.conf`) then their username should not be prefixed with the short domain name for that realm?